# How to show message only once?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have profile form with fields, that use should fill.

After submit button I do redirect to another controller(page).

How can I show message there only once? I mean that if user will update again profile, message will not showen more.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will only show message one time:

```
if($user_update) {
      if(Session::has('update_profile_message') {
          return redirect()->back(); //or wherever you want to redirect
        } else {
          return redirect()->back()->with('update_profile_message', 'Your profile has been updated successfully.');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
public function deleteObject($ho_id) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'My message.'); //return back and set a session key, message
}
```

Your code (layout that you want to extend)

```
@if (Session::has('message'))<!-- check if hash message key in session -->
    <div class="callout callout-info">
       <h4>
        Message
       </h4>
       <p>{{ Session::get('message') }}</p><!-- show the message -->
    </div>              
@endif
```

Hope this works!

Comment: This will only show it once every time a user update his profile, @Hamama

Answer (score 0):

You just need to redirect with flashing session data. For example,
In your routes file, you may have this:

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Update the user's profile...

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

In your blade file, check and show the 'message' stored in sessions

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

For more info, visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data